# java.lang.Security Exception

Tags: spring, cross-domain, weblogic, jndi

i implemented spring application which is running based on schedulers  in weblogic 10. server.
while i am deploying it. i am getting above exception.

here is my stack trace

```
   java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[bpm_weblogic, AdminChannelUsers, Administrators, AppTesters, CrossDomainConnectors, Deployers, Monitors, Operators, OracleSystemGroup]
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.seal(SecurityServiceManager.java:833)
    at weblogic.security.service.IdentityUtility.authenticatedSubjectToIdentity(IdentityUtility.java:30)
    at weblogic.security.service.RoleManager.getRoles(RoleManager.java:183)
    at weblogic.security.service.AuthorizationManager.isAccessAllowed(AuthorizationManager.java:375)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.checkPermission(ServerNamingNode.java:442)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.checkLookup(ServerNamingNode.java:423)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:180)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.unbind(BasicNamingNode.java:565)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.unbind(WLEventContextImpl.java:173)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.unbind(InitialContext.java:435)
    at com.tcs.controller.BpmController.run(BpmController.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

my spring application is running in one weblogic environment and i am calling bpm which is running in another weblogic environment.
here if don't call bpm i am not getting exception and if i user dataSource instead of jndi it is working fine.
but the problme is i have to call the bpm and i can't user dataSource configuration in production.

here is my controller class

```
public String executeBpm(User user) {
        IBPMContext context = null;
        String status = null;

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("executeBpm method starts");
        }
        try {
            if (user.getUserId() != null && !("").equals(user.getUserId())) {

                context = ITBABPMContext.getIBPMContextUsingName(user.getUserId());
            }
            HashMap<String, Object> elements = (HashMap<String, Object>) user.getMap();
            UpdateTaskDetails updates = new UpdateTaskDetails();
            if (user.getTaskId() != null && !("").equals(user.getTaskId())) {
                updates.setTaskID(user.getTaskId());
            }

            if (user.getTaskId() != null && !("").equals(user.getTaskId())) {
                updates.setTaskOutcome(user.getTaskOutcome());
            }
            if (user.getUserComment() != null && !("").equals(user.getUserComment())) {
                updates.setUserComment(user.getUserComment());
            }

            if (!elements.isEmpty() && elements.size() > 0) {
                updates.setElementList(elements);
            }
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("executeBpm method ends");
            }
            status = ITBAACMUtil.updateTaskOutcome(updates, context);
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                bpmProcessorService.write(user.getUserId(), user.getSeqNo());
            }

        } catch (ITBABPMRuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BPMServiceClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BPMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
```

my dao class

```
public void write(String userId,Long seqNo){
        try{
            String query=messageSource.getMessage(BPMConstants.FAILED_QUERY,new Object[]{Long.toString(seqNo)},Locale.US);
            jdbcTemplate.update(query);

    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("exception at updating the status to failed ..");
        logger.error(e.getStackTrace());
    }
```

}

here one thing is cross domain mapping is are already there and other applications are running just fine. so i don't think this is the issue with cross domain mapping.
here is my configuration file.

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" /> 

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="MCDataSource"/>
    </bean>  

     <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager" /> 

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"/>
    </bean>


<!--   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.19.8.159:1521/OIM.itba.gov.in" />
    <property name="username" value="AppDB"></property>
    <property name="password" value="AppDB"></property>
    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    </bean>     -->




    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

  <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>  

   <bean id="runScheduler" class="com.app.controller.BpmController" />
       <task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" cron="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
   </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey it seems your problem is you are not switching the context correctly. Once you open up the IBPM context then you are coming back and trying to lookup on your local jndi tree but you have IBPM context credentials which do not authenticate on your local weblogic. You need to open a new context before you perform a jndi lookup operation to your datasource.

Here is some sample code:

```
jndiTemplate(org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate) { bean ->
    bean.scope = "prototype"
    environment = [
      "java.naming.factory.initial":"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory",
      "java.naming.security.principal"  : "username",
      "java.naming.security.credentials": "password"
      ]
}

dataSource(org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean){
    jndiTemplate = ref(jndiTemplate)
    jndiName = "name"
    exposeAccessContext=true
}
```

Then when you want to lookup the jndi you can something like.
Inject the jndiTemplate and:

```
jndiTemplate.context.getProperties()
```

Or

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(jndiTemplate.getEnvironment());
```

You can then close it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. you are absolutely correct. i can create connection with new context. but can you please tell me how can i achieve this with spring.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you clarify one thing here. what is the diff b/w using jndiTemplate and jdbcTemplate.

Comment: JndiTemplate allows you to lookup and bind a Jndi resource (datasource). JbdcTemplate allows you to execute Sql statements using a datasource.